# How to display duration using Google Maps?

Tags: android

I am trying to display to the user just the duration between two locations using latitude and longitude. I am having trouble with permissions which I am not sure how to handle it.

Here is my doInBackground code:

```
protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {


            try {
                LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) MyCustomHomeActivity.this
                        .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

                // getting GPS status
                boolean isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                        .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                // getting network status
                boolean isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                        .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                    // no network provider is enabled
                } else {

                    // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                    if (isGPSEnabled) {

                            if (locationManager != null) {
                                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                                if (location != null) {
                                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            String shuLat = "41.2207188";
            String shuLong = "-73.24168179999999";
            String forecastJsonStr = null;

            String myUrlSetup = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin="+latitude + "," + longitude +"&destination="+shuLat +"," + shuLong + "&departure_time=now&traffic_model=best_guess&key=AIzaSyB6l8vrnspw2-1Q_cnzO03JlAsIOMl-7bs";
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            try {

                URL url;
                url = new URL(myUrlSetup);


                // Create the request to GoogleMapAPI, and open the connection
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Read the input stream into a String
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                if (inputStream == null) {
                    // Nothing to do.
                    return null;
                }
                System.out.println("I am in doInBackground step3");
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                    // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                    // buffer for debugging.
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }

                if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                    // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                    return null;
                }
                forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();

                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Forecast string: " + forecastJsonStr);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);
                // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attemping
                // to parse it.
                return null;
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                    }
                }
            }

            try {
                System.out.println("I am just in front of calling getDurationDataFromJson");
                return getDurationDataFromJson(forecastJsonStr);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return new String[0];
        }//end doInBackground
```

Here is my getDurationDataFromJSON code:

```
private String[] getDurationDataFromJson(String forecastJsonStr)
        throws JSONException {

    // These are the names of the JSON objects that need to be extracted.
    final String OWM_ROUTES = "routes";
    final String OWM_LEGS = "legs";
    final String OWM_DURATION = "duration";
    final String OWM_TEXT = "text";


    String[] resultStrs = new String[0];
    String duration;

    JSONObject durationJson = new JSONObject(forecastJsonStr);

    JSONArray routeArray = durationJson.getJSONArray(OWM_ROUTES);

    JSONArray legArray = routeArray.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray(OWM_LEGS);

    //Duration
    JSONObject durationObj = legArray.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject(OWM_DURATION);

    duration = durationObj.getString(OWM_TEXT);

    resultStrs[0] = duration;

    System.out.println("Duration is: " + duration);
    for (String s : resultStrs) {
        System.out.println("Duration entry: " + s);
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Duration entry: " + s);
    }
    return resultStrs;

}
```

Trouble I am facing is the following part in doInBackGround code:

```
location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

Error is:

```
Call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should explicitly check to see if permission is available(with `check permission`) or explicitly handle a potential `SecurityException`.
```

I am not sure if I am going in the right direction. Please guide me through this.

Comment: can you show your permissions from manifest? which OS version you are trying? are you familiar with new permision api since API23?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> This is what I have in Manifest

Comment: check out [https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: I am pretty new to android development. I am not really familiar with new permission api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Android API level (23), permissions are requested at running time, here you have de official documentation:

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Basically, you need to check if the device Android API level is >= 23, and if so, request the required permissions. Try something like this:

```
if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)
        //Ask for needed permissions following the docs mentioned above
}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use [FusedLocationProviderApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi)
to get last known location.

But before doing anything with location you need make sure that you have provided

- **android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION**
- **android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION**

in your manifest.xml.

Now I came to your point. From API Level-23 android indrouces explicit permission seeking feature. To provide this you need to follow some steps.

I hereby attach some code blocks for your help-

1. Checker of required permission states and device location service

   ```js
   public boolean isLocationEnabled() {
       int locationMode = 0;
       String locationProviders;

       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
           try {
               locationMode = Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE);
           } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

           return locationMode != Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF;

       } else {
           locationProviders = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
           return !TextUtils.isEmpty(locationProviders);
       }

   }

   public boolean hasCoarseLocationPermission() {
       return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
   }

   public boolean hasFineLocationPermission() {
       return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
   }
   ```
2. Now launch your activity/fragment after checking and providing expicit permission

```js
private void initiateYourActivityCallAfterCheckingPermission() {
           if (hasCoarseLocationPermission() && hasFineLocationPermission()) {
               if (locationUtil.isLocationEnabled()) {
                   startYourLocationActivity();
               } 
           } else if (!hasFineLocationPermission() && hasCoarseLocationPermission()) {
               requestBothLocationPermission();
           } else if (hasFineLocationPermission() && hasCoarseLocationPermission()) {
               requestFineLocationPermission();
           } else if (hasFineLocationPermission() && !hasCoarseLocationPermission()) {
               requestCoarseLocationPermission();
           }
}

private void requestBothLocationPermission() {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(SplashActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                && ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(SplashActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SplashActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    REQUEST_BOTH_LOCATION);
        }
    }

    private void requestCoarseLocationPermission() {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(SplashActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {

        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SplashActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION);
        }
    }

    private void requestFineLocationPermission() {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(SplashActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SplashActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);
        }
    }

/**
     * to process permission result
     */
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case General.REQUEST_BOTH_LOCATION:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    startYourLocationActivity();
                } 
                break;
            case General.REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    startYourLocationActivity();
                } 
                break;
            case General.REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    startYourLocationActivity();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Hope this will help.